# Reading in files stored in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, read.table

I have three directories that each contain about 2,000 files - the files have the same exact format but they are from 3 different sources. For each set of 3 files, I need to read in the data, merge them, and do some calculations and store the output.  I've already got my script running for a test case; now I'm trying to loop it over all the files (so, 2000 sets of 3 files of each).

I only want to read in 3 at a time, of course. I thought of this approach: create a dataframe of files where the columns represent the 3 types and the rows represent files. I do that here:

```
type1Files <- list.files(path="path_to_dir", pattern="*.tsv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
type2Files <- list.files(path="path_to_dir", pattern="*.tsv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
type3Files <- list.files(path="path_to_dir", pattern="*.tsv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

enter files.df <- cbind.data.frame(type1=type1Files,type2=type2Files,type3=type3Files)
```

Now I need to read these files by column, looping over rows so only 3 files get opened in one loop.  The issue is that I cannot read in a file using read.table, and I think it's because of the format of the filename (read.table() is not being fed the right format).

```
head(files.df) #confirms that each file is not surrounded by double quotes as required by read.table
```

My read.table statement:

```
type1.df <- read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Where, for x, I have tried the following:

```
shQuote(files.df[1,"type1"])
dQuote(files.df[1,"type1"])

file.t <- files.df[1,"type1"]
paste0('"',file.t,'"')
```

I've tried them all directly in read.table() as well as saving to objects and naming the object in read.table().  I even trying using cat() because I thought the escaped quotes might be the problem.  Nothing works. I either get "unexpected input" as the error, or the typical error: "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection."  Furthermore, if I paste that exact filename that is printed in the error into my read.table() statement, it runs just fine.  So, after many hours, I am stumped.

Can this be done in this way?
Thank you all for your advice.

Comment: How about: `type1.df<-lapply(files.df[,"type1"], read.table, header=F, sep"\t", stringsAsFactors=F)`. You end up with a list of dataframe from your `type1` files.

Comment: I corrected a typo that you might have missed in the third line of code.

Comment: Yout `read.table` statement runs fine with tab-delimited files generated from excel. the problem might be that it's not a normal tsv file. We'd have to inspect the file to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider iterating directly from the lists without using an intermediary dataframe. With `Map`, you can pass each list of 2,000 dataframes for iterative `cbind` calls across all three types. Below `cbind.data.frame` prefixes columns with *type1*, *type2*, and *type3*.

```
bind_dfs <- function(x,y,z) {
  xdf <- read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  ydf <- read.table(y, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  zdf <- read.table(z, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  cbind.data.frame(type1=xdf, type2=ydf, type3=zdf)
}

dfList <- Map(bind_dfs, type1Files, type2Files, type3Files)
```

Also, to run your calculations, you can either extend the `bind_dfs` method

```
bind_dfs <- function(x,y,z) {
  xdf <- read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  ydf <- read.table(y, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  zdf <- read.table(z, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  df <- cbind(xdf, ydf, zdf)
  df <- #... other calculations
  return(df)
}
```

Or use another loop on dataframe list:

```
newdfList <- lapply(dfList, function(df){
   df <- # ... other calculations
   return(df)
})
```